# Remove a class which is not recognized by DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a interactive map, which triggers an overlay image (which highlights the selected area)

But now I add classes to an div and I want to delete them if I highlight an other area. First I tried the starts with indicator to remove classes which starts with `hl-` this is my js file:

```
$('.btn-pointer').click(function() {
       $('.highlight-layer').removeClass('[class^="hl-"]');
});

$('.btn-sp').click(function() {
    $('.highlight-layer').addClass('hl-sp');
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
});

$('.btn-vp').click(function() {
    $('.highlight-layer').addClass('hl-vp');
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
});

$('.btn-sl').click(function() {
    $('.highlight-layer').addClass('hl-sl');
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
});

$('.btn-ec').click(function() {
    $('.highlight-layer').addClass('hl-ec');
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<div>
    <img src="../img/map/map-full.jpg" alt="">
    <button class="btn btn-sp btn-pointer" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<h2>Safaripark</h2>">Safaripark</button>
    <button class="btn btn-vp btn-pointer" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<h2>Vakantiepark</h2>">Vakantiepark</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sl btn-pointer" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<h2>Speelland</h2>">Speelland</button>
    <button class="btn btn-ec btn-pointer" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<h2>Event Center</h2>">Event Center</button>
    <div class="highlight-layer hl-ec"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7frnLx5/2/) but never added external Resources so the error it gives me is the following: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: Ok, that's what you tried, what happens? Does it fail? If so, how? Are there any errors? In the console?

Comment: `removeClass` doesn't work that way, it doesn't take partial attributes, it takes the classname(s) you want to remove, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It does not give me any errors, it just keeps adding the classes to `.highlight-layer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the callback for `removeClass` to filter out the classes you want to remove based on a starting string etc

```
$('.highlight-layer').removeClass(function(i, klass) {
    var remove = 'hl-';

    return klass.split(/\s/).filter(function(k) {
        return k.indexOf(remove) === 0;
    }).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: Thank you forget to wrap it in my click function 0.0''

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass` doesn't accept a selector, it accepts a space-delimited series of classes to remove. So just list the ones you want to remove:

```
$('.highlight-layer').removeClass('hl-sp hl-vp hl-sl hl-ec');
```

It's fine if one (or indeed all) of them aren't on any given element; the one(s) that is/are will be removed.

Example:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $(".highlight-layer").removeClass("hl-sp hl-vp hl-sl hl-ec");
});
```

```css
.hl-sp {
  color: red;
}
.hl-vp {
  color: green;
}
.hl-sl {
  color: blue;
}
.hl-ec {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Remove">
  
  <div class="highlight-layer hl-sp">Starts out with hl-sp</div>
  <div class="highlight-layer hl-vp">Starts out with hl-vp</div>
  <div class="highlight-layer hl-sl">Starts out with hl-sl</div>
  <div class="highlight-layer hl-ec">Starts out with hl-ec</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This gives me a weird flicker when switching

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer: If you want to keep one of them, just leave it out of the string. If you'd made a [mcve] successfully (better to use Stack Snippets -- the `<>` toolbar button -- here on SO than jsFiddle), I'd be able to show you how to do that in context.

Comment: I don't think the issue here is just removing the class, both answers posted do that swimmingly. It seems like you're trying to manipulate classes to do some magic with Bootstrap popovers, that are generated dynamically with their own set of classes, and somewhere along the way, you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7frnLx5/4/)**.

You have just to change one line in your code and it will works check the code below that remove all the classes and keep just the essential one `highlight-layer` :

```
$('.btn-pointer').click(function() {
    $('.highlight-layer').removeClass().addClass('highlight-layer');
});
```

Like this the element classes are always two `highlight-layer` and clicker button class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extension to `jQuery` which would loop through elements returned from selector and remove list.

Following is a basic example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk4z5t4e/3/).

```js
$.fn.removeClasses = function(regex) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, function(el) {
    var class_list = el.classList;
    var filtered_list = Array.prototype.filter.call(class_list, function(c) {
      return regex.test(c);
    });
    console.log(filtered_list);
    $(el).removeClass(filtered_list.join(" "))
  });
}

$(".foo").on("click", function() {
  var reg = /^test/;
  $(this).removeClasses(reg);
});
```

```css
.test {
  background: #333;
}
.test1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.test2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.test3 {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test1 test2 test3 foo">
  Test
</div>
```